# Why am I getting AttributeError: 'IP' Object has no attribute 'SourceIp'

Tags: python

I'm using black hat python book.For practice i'm trying to make `Raw Socket` and decode it using `struct`.I'm getting `AttributeError: Object has no attribute` when I am trying to get `self.SourceIp` from within the same object context.I checked `TABS` and `Spaces`.So what's wrong? Please help.

Code:

```
import socket
import os
import struct
from ctypes import *





class RAWSOCKET:

    class INFO:
        host = "0.0.0.0"

    class IP(Structure):
        __fields__ = [
                ("ihl", c_ubyte, 4),
                ("Version", c_ubyte, 4),
                ("TypeOfService", c_ubyte),
                ("Len", c_ushort),
                ("Id", c_ushort),
                ("OffSet", c_ushort),
                ("TimeToLive", c_ubyte),
                ("ProtocolNumber", c_ubyte),
                ("HeaderChecksum", c_ushort),
                ("SourceIp", c_ulong),
                ("DestinationIp", c_ulong)
        ]

        def __new__(self, SocketBuffer = None):
            return self.from_buffer_copy(SocketBuffer)
            
            
        def __init__(self, SocketBuffer = None):
            self.ProtocolMap = {1:"ICMP", 6:"TCP", 17:"UDP"}
            self.SourceAddress = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L",self.SourceIp))
            self.DestinationAddress = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L", self.DestinationIp))
            try:
                self.Protocol = self.ProtocolMap[self.ProtocolNumber]
                
            except:
                self.Protocol = str(self.ProtocolNumber)

class SNIFFER:
    if os.name == "nt":
        SocketProtocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP

    else:
        SocketProtocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP

    Sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, SocketProtocol)
    Sniffer.bind((RAWSOCKET.INFO.host, 0))
    Sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    if os.name == "nt":
        Sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

    try:
        while True:
            RawBuffer = Sniffer.recvfrom(65565)[0]
            IpHeader = RAWSOCKET.IP(RawBuffer[0:20])
            print(f"{IpHeader.SourceAddress} -------------------> {IpHeader.DestinationAddress} [{IpHeader.Protocol}]")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        if os.name == "nt":
            Sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO.RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RawSocketV1.py", line 44, in <module>
    class SNIFFER:
  File "RawSocketV1.py", line 60, in SNIFFER
    IpHeader = RAWSOCKET.IP(RawBuffer[0:20])
  File "RawSocketV1.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.SourceAddress = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack("<L",self.SourceIp))
AttributeError: 'IP' object has no attribute 'SourceIp'
```

Comment: Is "\_\_fields__" standard functionality? Or you meant "\_\_slots__" ?

Comment: __fields__ is not special cased by Python. It is just a name